# Create a canonical "parent" product in Django Oscar programmatically

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-oscar

I'm trying to use a modified version of the [django-oscar import_oscar_catalogue](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/partner/importers.py) class to import a bunch of products from a CSV, and on the first encounter of a product (defined by title), create a canonical parent product, and then for all future encounters create a child product under that parent product.

This seems to work, but the canonical product does not reflect the combined stock levels of the child product, nor display the correct attributes for that product. It does correctly list them as variations within the django dashboard though.

How can I programmatically create this child/parent relationship in products, with the correct stock records?

Relevant code:

```
def _create_item(self, upc, title, product_class, other_product_attributes):
    product_class, __ \
        = ProductClass.objects.get_or_create(name=product_class)
    try:
        parent = Product.objects.get(title=title)
        item = Product()
        item.parent = parent
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        # Here is where I think it might need to be changed
        # Maybe pitem = ParentProduct() or something?
        pitem = Product()
        pitem.upc = upc
        pitem.title = title
        pitem.other_product_attributes = other_product_attributes
        # Here parent item is saved to db
        pitem.save()
        # Create item because no parent was found
        item = Product()
        parent = Product.objects.get(title=title)
        #Set parent
        item.parent = parent
    # Customize child attributes
    item.product_class = product_class
    item.title = title
    item.other_product_attributes = other_product_attributes
    # Save the child item
    item.save()

def _create_stockrecord(self, item, partner_name, partner_sku, price_excl_tax,
    num_in_stock, stats):
    # Create partner and stock record
    partner, _ = Partner.objects.get_or_create(
        name=partner_name)
    try:
        stock = StockRecord.objects.get(partner_sku=partner_sku)
    except StockRecord.DoesNotExist:
        stock = StockRecord()
        stock.num_in_stock = 0
    # General attributes
    stock.product = item
    stock.partner = partner
    # SKU will be unique for every object
    stock.partner_sku = partner_sku
    stock.price_excl_tax = D(price_excl_tax)
    stock.num_in_stock += int(num_in_stock)
    # Save the object to database
    stock.save()
```

The `create_stockrecord()` creates a record of 1 stock for each unique item variation, but these variation's stockrecords don't translate to the parent item.

**EDIT:**
I have updated the class with a method that explicitly calls `ProductClass.objects.track_stock()` against the ProductClass instance, and I'm calling it after looping through all rows of the CSV file (passing it the name of the one product class I use currently). However, when looking at the stock in dashboard, none of the child/variations stock is being counted against the parent.

```
def track_stock(self, class_name):
    self.logger.info("ProductClass name: %s" % class_name)
    product_class = ProductClass.objects.get_or_create(name=class_name)
    self.logger.info("ProductClass: %s" % str(product_class))
    self.logger.info("TrackStock: %s" % str(product_class[0].track_stock))
    product_class[0].track_stock = True
    self.logger.info("TrackStock: %s" % str(product_class[0].track_stock))
    product_class[0].save()


INFO Starting catalogue import
INFO  - Importing records from 'sample_inventory.csv'
INFO  - Flushing product data before import
INFO Parent items: 6, child items: 10
INFO ProductClass name: ClassName
INFO ProductClass: (<ProductClass: ClassName>, False)
INFO TrackStock: True
INFO TrackStock: True
```

I have checked the admin page, only 1 ProductClass is created, and it has the same name as is being passed to `track_stock()`. Is there something else that needs to be done to enable this feature? [track_stock()](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/ref/apps/catalogue.html) documentation is kind of sparse. In the output, track_stock looks like it is true in both instances. Does it have to be False while the child_objects are created, and then flipped to True?

Answer (score 5):

To be able to correctly reflect the stock levels for any [Product](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ref/apps/catalogue.html#oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models.AbstractProduct) you need to have a [Partner](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ref/apps/partner.html#oscar.apps.partner.abstract_models.AbstractPartner) that will supply the Product and then you need to have [StockRecord](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ref/apps/partner.html#oscar.apps.partner.abstract_models.AbstractStockRecord) that links the Partner and the Products together.

First make sure that you have all that information in the database for each one of your [Product](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ref/apps/catalogue.html#oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models.AbstractProduct) variations.

Then you need to update your [ProductClass](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ref/apps/catalogue.html#oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models.AbstractProductClass) and set the "[track_stock](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ref/apps/catalogue.html#oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models.AbstractProductClass)" attribute as True since its None by default.

You also need to remove the [ProductClass](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ref/apps/catalogue.html#oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models.AbstractProductClass) from your child products since they inherit the [ProductClass](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ref/apps/catalogue.html#oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models.AbstractProductClass) from their Parent Product.

EDIT 1:

To add attributes to a Product you have to add a ProductAttribute for the ProductClass and then you can set the attributes directly on the Product [like this example](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/topics/modelling_your_catalogue.html#product-attributes).

EDIT 2:

You also need to set the "net_stock_level" on the StockRecord.

To get a more in depth look into how Oscar gets the stock levels look into [Selector](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/stable/_modules/oscar/apps/partner/strategy.html#Base.fetch_for_parent). This class determines which pricing, tax and stock level strategies to use which you might need to customize in the future if you want to charge tax or offer different pricing based on the user.

Comment: Yes sir, if you have a product_class on child product they behave differently and if you don't have the track_stock attribute on the class it won't care about your StockRecords. Regarding setting attributes dynamically you need to add the attributes to the ProductClass and then create a ProductAttributeValue

Comment: I've added more info in the answer. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: You also might need to set the "net_stock_level" on the StockRecord.

Comment: I don't believe you need a StockRecord on the Parent Product. As long as the children have this value you should be able to see inventory counts on the Parent Product.

Comment: Please let me know if you we're able to properly show the stock record counts on the Canonical Product.

Comment: For me, i want create product variants, only was necessary put `track_stock` and yes, now i can create product variants manually.

Answer (score 0):

After some research from the [test factory](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/test/factories/__init__.py), I solved the issue by specifying

```
product.stucture = 'parent'
```

On the parent object, and

```
product.structure = 'child'
```

on the child object. I also needed to change the custom attributes of my objects to a dict `product_attributes`, and then set each value on the object:

```
if product_attributes:
        for code, value in product_attributes.items():
            product_class.attributes.get_or_create(name=code, code=code)
            setattr(product.attr, code, value)
```

It was not necessary to create a stock record for each parent object, as they track the stock records of the child objects to which they are associated. It was also not necessary to set `track_stock = True`, as it is set to `True` by default when creating a `Product()`

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35071361/6) to the question [Create a canonical "parent" product in Django Oscar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071361/create-a-canonical-parent-product-in-django-oscar-programmatically) by the OP [Tui Popenoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1751129/tui-popenoe) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>